# How to handle "if" my document doesn't set a particular value?

Tags: conditionals

I'm still learning latex, and  copying and pasting a lot of what I don't understand, so apologies for the ignorance.

Assuming a document like this:

```
\documentclass{mycls}


\title{A title}
\targetaudience{A target audience}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

In my `.cls` I have something like this:

```
\newcommand{\targetaudience}[1]{\gdef\tf@targetaudience{#1}}
\targetaudience{\@empty}
```

I am trying to add content to my `.cls`, the part that defines the `\maketitle` page. I want to add to the title page, something conditionally, i.e. something like this:

```
\ifx\tf@targetaudience\empty
\else
       \textbf{Target Audience:} & \tf@targetaudience\\
\fi
```

I know that people like to have a "minimum working example" but I honestly have no idea how to turn what I have into an example. I am googling for different ways of doing "if" and nothing has worked so far. Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how want define "nothing". Some people define nothing to be a specific thing that exists, while others test for nothing as being something that doesn't exist.

Let's consider the following content in your `.cls`:

```
\newcommand{\targetaudience}[1]{\gdef\tf@targetaudience{#1}}
\targetaudience{\@empty}
```

You're defining `\targetaudience` to redefine (and/or overwrite) `\tf@targetaudience`, and immediately setting it to `\@empty`. So, you can test whether `\tf@targetaudience` looks like `\@empty` in order to see whether the user didn't do anything:

```
\expandafter\ifx\expandafter\@empty\tf@targetaudience
  Target audience not set.
\else
  Target audience set: \@tf@targetaudience
\fi
```

We have to expand `\tf@targetaudience` in order to test it against `\@empty`. Alternatively, consider

```
\newcommand{\targetaudience}[1]{\gdef\tf@targetaudience{#1}}
```

*without* setting any `\targetaudience`. Now you can test whether `\tf@targetaudience` exists or not:

```
\@ifundefined{tf@targetaudience}
  {Target audience not set.}
  {Target audience set: \@tf@targetaudience}
```

An e-TeX approach similar to the above would be

```
\ifcsname tf@targetaudience \endcsname
  Target audience set: \@tf@targetaudience
\else
  Target audience not set.
\fi
```

Comment: I really appreciate the time you took to provide such a helpful answer to a latex newbie! This is perfect.